# yii2 dependent autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, widget, yii2

I have two fields in a form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'bill_country')->widget(AutoComplete::className(), ['options' => ['class' => 'form-control'], 'clientOptions' => ['source' => $country_name]])->label('Country') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'bill_zip')->widget(AutoComplete::className(), ['options' => ['class' => 'form-control'], 'clientOptions' => ['source' => '/city/list/+id']])->label('Zip') ?>
```

Based on the selection of the first block, I want to change the 'source' of the second one. +id is a javascript variable...
So I vant to get the value of the first autocomplete with val(), assign it to var id, and then pass this id to the source of the second.
Can I do that?
Or should I use another option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but Yii2 has nothing to do with it. You are doing this on page, in the browser, it is a javascript issue. Look at the page and you will see the code that gets created by Yii and the widgets, you should not use the automatic autocomplete but create your own code to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did! I wanted to use the widget by yii2 to get the source, but it seems, it cannot take a javascript variable. I wanted to list the zip codes only for one specific country, that's why I created an initial array with yii2. After that, I have created the jquery code to read the id from the first autocomplete, and update the source array for the second (zip) one. I will post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

So, the code:

```
$this->registerJs("
    var country = '';
    $('#partner-bill_country').autocomplete({
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            country = (ui.item.country_id);
            $('#partner-bill_zip').autocomplete({
                source: '/city/list/'+country
            });
        }
    });
$('#partner-bill_zip').autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#partner-bill_city').val(ui.item.citname);
    }
});
", View::POS_READY, 'partner_script');
//initial arrays:
$city_zip = frontend\models\City::find()
    ->select(['CONCAT(cit_zip, " ", cit_name) as label', 'cit_zip as value', 'cit_id as id', 'cit_name as citname'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

$country_name = frontend\models\Country::find()
    ->select(['CONCAT(country_code, " ", country_name) as label', 'country_name as value','id as country_id'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
?>
<div class="partner-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_country')->widget(AutoComplete::className(), ['options' => ['class' => 'form-control'], 'clientOptions' => ['source' => $country_name]])->label('Country') ?>
                  <?= $form->field($model, 'bill_zip')->widget(AutoComplete::className(), ['options' => ['class' => 'form-control'], 'clientOptions' => ['source' => $city_name]])->label('Zip') ?>
```

Comment: Excellent! Works fine!

Comment: Hi, Sly good approach, can we clear more about:--   source: '/city/list/'+country (i think it belongs to someone action) so plz clarify that.

Comment: Oh, hi @sprytechies, sorry, I did not see that you asked something... So the  `/city/list/+country` gets a list of cities, based on the `country id` (`parent id`). The action is simple, get the children of this parent... Is that clear now?