# Yii2 Fill multilpe fields based on selected value from Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii2

I have model containing column cnic,name,age,city etc.
What i want here when user starts input cnic value, if that cnic is already in database then full cnic value should appear and on select that value, values of name,age,city automatically be filled in text inputs.
currently it is.

```
  $data = Patient::find()->all();
    foreach($data as $cnics){
        $cnic[] = $cnics->cnic;
    }

   echo $form->field($model, 'cnic')->widget(yii\jui\AutoComplete::classname(), [
        'clientOptions' => [
            'source' => $cnic,
            'select' => //some code
],  

<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'age')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Comment: You may use onchange concept :
This might be helpful to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425942/yii2-dropdownlist-onchange-change-autocomplete-widget-source-attribute?rq=1

Comment: @vijaynathji i read that link... My situation is different to that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'clientOptions' => [
            'source' => $cnic,
            'select' => new \yii\web\JsExpression("function( event, ui ) {
                    var cnic = ui.item.value;
                    complete(cnic);
            }")
        ],
```

in jquery code

```
function complete(id){

        $.ajax({
           url: "?r=patient/autocomplete",
           type: 'post',
           data: {cnic: id},
           success: function(data) {

               var obj = JSON.parse(data);

                $('#patient-name').val(obj[0].name);
                $('#patient-age').val(obj[0].age);
                $('#patient-dob').val(obj[0].dob);
                $('#patient-address').val(obj[0].address);
                $('#patient-city').val(obj[0].city);
           }
        });
```

in controller

```
public function actionAutocomplete()
{
    $cnic = $_POST['cnic'];
    $query = ModelName::find()->where(['cnic'=> $cnic])->one();
    $data[] = ['name' => $query->name,'dob'=> $query->dob, 'age' =>$query->age, 'address'=> $query->address, 'city' => $query->city];
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```